# Networked Aframe - Screen Sharing Bug

Tags: javascript, webrtc, aframe, webvr, aframe-networked

While developing a multi-user VR room with networked-aframe, i run into a bug with the screen sharing option simmilar to the one in the file: `/examples/basic-multi-streams.html`

I've tried different approaches and tests but couldn't get that one fixed.

The networked-aframe repo:

https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe

There is also a thread about this bug on github:

https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe/issues/299

Here you can find the example file where the bug exists:

https://naf-examples.glitch.me/basic-multi-streams.html

There is a note in this example file describing the bug:

> Known issues with this demo, some cases are not handled:
> - If participant A shares their screen, the partipant B sees the other participant's screen.
> When participant A stops their screen share, the other participant will see a frozen screen, the last image received.
> - If participant A starts screen share, stops, and restarts the screen share, the other participant won't see it.

Here is the full repo with all the example source files.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/naf-examples

I would love to fix this issue so the users could make presentations of their screen content easily in the VR scene.

Thanks for any help in advance!